# Model is NULL in Display Template page when using GET in .Net Core Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have recently migrated to VS 2022 and .Net 7.0 (from .Net Core 3.1) and am having a problem accessing a model in the Display Template (page) using a GET. I'm not sure if this has anything to do with the migrating part, but when I POST the page the Model Value in the debugger is there, but when I use a GET, the Value is null?

Here is my stripped down code in UserNewRegisterTest.cshtml.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using LimitedPlay.Areas.User.Models;

namespace LimitedPlay.Areas.User.Pages
{
    public class UserNewRegisterTestModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public UserEditSP UserEditSP { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public string StringTest { get; set; }


        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            UserEditSP UserEditSP = new UserEditSP();
            UserEditSP.NewPassword = "NewPwd";

            StringTest = "Test";

            return Page();
        }

        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            UserEditSP UserEditSP = new UserEditSP();
            UserEditSP.NewPassword = "NewPwd";

            StringTest = "Test";

            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

And UserNewRegisterTest.cshtml:

```
@page "/Register/NewTest"

@model LimitedPlay.Areas.User.Pages.UserNewRegisterTestModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Register (New User)";
}
```

So when I browse UserNewRegisterTest.cshtml in the debugger, and look at 'this.Model' this is what shows with a GET:
[image]

Why is the UserEditSP Model showing as null?

When I edit an existing record (where I retrieve a record from DB and POST the page from a button), everything works great, including password options set in Startup.cs (i.e. options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;).

Also, I'm not sure if this matters, but I'm using Identity and EF Framework to resister/login users. I've created my own Register.cshtml page, and for a local account, I wanted to use the Model Validation along with JQuery validate.js and validate-unobtrusive.js. And just to be thorough, I also upgraded all NuGet packages to the latest 7.0.4 versions.

As I said, it works great when editing an existing record via POST, but when I try to use GET and UserEditSP UserEditSP = new UserEditSP(); it shows as null on the page. What am I missing here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers... :)

P.S. I found this [Razor Pages on async Get model is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58129332/razor-pages-on-async-get-model-is-null) and tried various combinations with the public ... OnGet(), but the model is always null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you have shown, you are not assigning a value to the `UserEditSP` property anywhere. In the `OnGet` and `OnPost` handlers, you instantiate a different instance of `UserEditSP`:

```
UserEditSP UserEditSP = new UserEditSP();
```

If you want to set a value to the property in the `OnGet` handler, you can do this:

```
UserEditSP = new UserEditSP{ NewPassword = "NewPwd"};
```

It works in the `OnPost` handler because the model binder instantiated the property and attempts to bind values to it from the request. If you want it to work in the same way in the `OnGet` handler, add `SupportsGet = true` to the `BindProperty` attribute:

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true]
public UserEditSP UserEditSP { get; set; }
```

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding

Comment: Tks @MikeBrind. The [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)] is what was needed. I was under the impression that SupportsGet was for binding route data (which I have been using), but never dawned on me that this would also apply to complex collections. BTW: Great resource, that website of yours... :)

I do have another question, being how all this started with trying to validate the password errors using _userManager.CreateAsync() before the user is registered, but I think this is a new topic so I'll create a new post. Tks again.